# WCF Certificate authentication on production server

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, ssl, x509certificate

I have created a WCF service with username/password custom authentication:

```
<userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
         customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="CCService.CustomUserNameValidator,CCService" />
        <serviceCertificate findValue="0d a6 2d 39 e1 28 ca f4 df af a9 90 21 ca c5 67 b8 61 b8 63" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
      </serviceCredentials>

  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="ServiceBinding">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">                        
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
```

Created a self-signed certificate in IIS 7 on development server. It works great. Clients (Windows application) were able to consume the service with https.

Now I would like to deploy it on production server. I have valid domain name and a certificate from verisign mapped to it in the production server.

1. Do I need to share the certificate with clients to consume the service?
2. Should clients require any certificates to be installed in their system?
3. Any additional configuration is required for production server?
4. What is public key? How can we generate it? When it is required?

Please guide me in right direction..

Your help is greatly appreciated!!!